# Graph of derivative of function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, graphing-functions

Is it possible to draw the graph of derivative of a function if we know the only graph of the function $f(x)$? If someone who did not study the function and just know the images. Is it possible we can tell the graph of derivative of that function without knowing actually what function is?

- graph of $\sin x$ and - $\cos x$ . But I am not able to find any relation.

Comment: Do you know what the geometric interpretation of the derivative of a function is? The derivative is the instantaneous slope of a given function. So from a graph, you can approximate the derivative of a function without knowing the exact expression of the function. It boils down to determining $\dfrac{\Delta f}{\Delta x}$ for multiple sections.

Comment: Drawing graph of a derivative of function from given function is fruitful. Please provide example with graph.thanks